# Scala: How to use custom function in parallel

Tags: function, scala, parallel-processing

This should be a quick one :)

Let's say I've got a function like this:

```
    def sort: List[Int] => List[Int]
```

and I want to parallelize it in a function called sortPar. Originally I'd thought that I'd need to do this:

```
    def sortPar: List[Int] => List[Int] = ls => sort(ls.par).toList
```

but of course that's not possible since sort expects a list rather than a ParSeq. After some time playing around with it I came up with this solution, but I'm not too sure about it:

```
    def sortPar: List[Int] => List[Int] = ls => sort(ls).par.toList
```

Does this achieve anything in terms of runtime? I get no red crosses in eclipse so I assume it should work, but I don't know if it actually sorts in parallel.

Many thanks
Curtis

Comment: In general, not every function is easily parallelizable and therefore there is no standard way of turning a function parallel. You would have to implement `sortPar` on your own.

Comment: So my function would run sort, then turn the result into a parSeq and then back into a list?

Comment: Exaclty. It would run your `sort` as-is.

Answer (score 1):

`def sortPar: List[Int] => List[Int] = ls => sort(ls).par.toList` does not do anything in parallel, since you first call `sort(ls)`, which sorts the list sequentially.

The calls after that are useless, because you turn the result into a parallel collection and directly translate it back to a sequential `List`.

**Things that you can/should consider:**

Regarding your first problem, there are traits that are designed for such cases, like `GenMap`, `GenSet` or in your case `GenSeq` might be the closest, since a `List` is a `Seq`.

So you can write your sort function like this:

```
def sort(seq: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]) = ...
```

and use it with a linear or parallel `Seq`.

```
sort(List(1,2,3))
sort(List(1,2,3).par)
```

So if you implement your `sort` with functions that are available to `GenSeq`, passing a sequential Seq will use the sequential implementation and passing a `ParSeq` might run those functions in parallel. (Some functions still run sequentially, like `sorted`)

If you don't use functions that have a parallel implementation, then you have to resort to taking care of parallelization yourself. I personally have no experience with it. You can look at some implementations in the source code.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala